# Cant get a Farseer Physics body’s rotation to follow the mouse

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

Here is what’s in my HandleKeyboard() method that is called from the Game1 Update method.

```
        MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();
        // the Vector2 that will hold the angle from the player to the mouse pointer.
        Vector2 mDirection = new Vector2(0, 0);

            // Get the current mouse position from the state update in the beginning of this method.
            Vector2 mPosition = new Vector2(mState.X, mState.Y);
            // Subtract the potsition of the player fromthe mouse pointer to get the exact angle in a vector2
            mDirection = mPosition - arrow.Position;

            // Control Rotation
            arrow.FixedRotation = true;
            // display the arrow in the rotation gathered above.
            arrow.Rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(mDirection.Y, mDirection.X);
```

From what I have read, this seems like the exact right thing to have the arrow look at my pointer. However when I rotate the mouse around the pointer it really doesn’t work properly.

It's hard to explain so here is a [youtube video](http://youtu.be/kufIaIhOGSc) displaying what’s happening

I really hope you can tell me what’s going wrong.

Comment: Your `mDirection` isn't strictly a direction, as there's no guarantee it will be of length 1. Try normalizing it before applying atan2.

Comment: tried normalizing, there is no difference unfortunately :(

Comment: The mouse position is relative to the upper left corner of the window, is your arrow's position relative to the center of it? If so, try doing `mPosition - Vector2(width/2.0, height/2.0) - arrow.Position` (where those would be width and height of the client area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Farseer (now named VelcroPhysics) works with the KMS (Kilo, Meter, Second) system (as explained in the section "Drawing the World" of this [slightly outdated documentation](https://github.com/Genbox/VelcroPhysics)). Because of that, the arrow's position is a really "small" vector (something close to (0, 0)) if you interpret it directly in pixels (which is what you're doing).

In order to get the correct position in pixels, you have to obtain a new Vector2 by calling this function provided by Farseer:

```
Vector2 arrowPositionInPixels = ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(arrow.Position);
```

Only then, you can continue with your code of obtaining `mDirection` and calculating the rotation.

Alternatively, you can obtain the position of the mouse in the unit system used by Farseer with:

```
Vector2 mousePositionKMS = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(mPosition);
```

And work in the KMS system. Both approaches should give the same rotation result. Just make sure you're always working in the same metric system (Farseer's KMS or pixels).